# Single-phase diesel generator to three-phase modification

Tags: generator, three-phase, single-phase

I have a 220 V, single-phase diesel generator and I would like to know if it's possible to modify it to generate 400 V, three-phase. I have never tried this before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it will cost more than getting a 3-phase generator. You'll need a single phase motor coupled shaft-t-shaft to a 3-phase generator. Power the motor with the gen set and power your load with the 3-phase generator.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to rewind the generator stator for three phase. Not impossible, but a daunting proposition. If you just want to have a source of three phase power, you could use a VFD. But a 220 VAC single phase input VFD will only give you 220 VAC three phase. So you would also need a step-up transformer. Probably best to use a 220-440 VAC single phase transformer (or autotransformer), and a 440-480 VAC VFD.